# How to fix a No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector JSONValue error

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, sbjson

I have encountered this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'JSONValue'.
```

The error occurs on:

`NSDictionary * root = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSArray *data = [root objectForKey:@"data"];`

does anyone know how to fix it? Could I be missing a JSON file?

[image]

Comment: You probably need to import the `NSString+SBJSON.h` file in the .m file containing the code you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to the top of your .m file, where you try to call it:

```
#import "NSString+SBJSON.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the NSString+JSON category.